# Can't install .deb files (or any packages, it seems)

Tags: apt, deb, troubleshooting

I just installed ubuntu, and anytime I try to open a .deb file, it just opens up in the archive manager. When I try to open with another application, there's no option for "software install" or "software center" which is what everyone else says is the thing to do. It seems I also can't install any packages from the terminal, whether I specify the file path or not. I'm trying to install discord, using the deb file listed on their home page https://discord.com

Comment: Try: [Posts containing 'install discord' - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=install+discord)

Comment: Or use Google to find another website, which describes that, for example: [How to Install Discord Application in Ubuntu and Other Linux Distributions](https://itsfoss.com/install-discord-linux/)

Comment: I find the [Discord snap](https://snapcraft.io/discord) to be quite easy to install and works well: `sudo snap install discord`. The deb is indeed not available directly from Ubuntu, though it could be if Discord wanted. If you still wish to install the deb, please edit your question to show us exactly what command you are using, and the complete system response or error. Details matter for this kind of troubleshooting.

Comment: We can be more specific when we know which Ubuntu product & release of that product you're asking about.